# Type error: Argument 1 passed to PayPal\Rest\ApiContext::setConfig() must be of the type array, null given, called in PaymentController.php on line 40

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to implement the paypal into my site. 
But I'm getting this error .

Type error: Argument 1 passed to PayPal\Rest\ApiContext::setConfig() must be of the type array, null given, called in D:\wamp64\www\vonservices\app\Http\Controllers\PaymentController.php on line 40 .
Here is my  controller code :

````
class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    private $_api_context;
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //parent::__construct();

        /** setup PayPal api context **/
        $paypal_conf = \Config::get('paypal');
        $this->_api_context = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential($paypal_conf['client_id'], $paypal_conf['secret']));
        $this->_api_context->setConfig($paypal_conf['settings']);
    }
    /**
     * Show the application paywith paypalpage.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function payWithPaypal()
    {
        return view('paywithpaypal');
    }
    /**
     * Store a details of payment with paypal.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

  }

  ?>```
````

Comment: Double-check what `$paypal_conf` and your PayPal config file contains. Use `Log::info($paypal_conf);` and look in `storage/logs` to see what is logged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\Config::get('paypal')` is an old way to find data in config. Try use `config('paypal')` and `php artisan config:cache` before using it.

Answer (score 2):

I know its very late but I had the same problem. What solved my problem was running

```
php artisan config:cache
```

And voila, it solved everything for me. Hope it works for others too.